# fadeToggle on multiple ids errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I come to you with an issue with jQuery / javascript and `.fadeToggle();`.

So I want to `P` elements with id.

Please see here:

```
$("#here").click(function(){
    $(".overlay, .popup").fadeToggle();
});


$("#there").click(function(){
    $(".overlay, .popup2").fadeToggle();
});
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aWhE/641/):

I want, ideally, to have several paragraphs with individual ids so I can add a pop up with differing content!

Comment: Are you having issues after you click the paragraph once? It seems to show the popup after I click one of the paragraphs

Comment: Your links are under the grey overlay which pops up. This is why you can't click the links again. If you want them to me over the overlay you will have to play with position and z-index css rules.

Comment: Ya it works fine for one, but if you are trying to click on a paragraph again, the div opens ONTOP of the paragraph, therefore you cannot trigger the next click, because you are clicking on the pop up, no the paragraph. This i why most sites have a close button associated with popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd usually use a custom data attribute for something like this. This way you can reuse the same function no matter how many elements you have...

```js
$('.clickable').click(function() {
    var popupTarget = $(this).data('popup');
   $('.overlay, '+popupTarget).fadeToggle();
});

/* click overlay to close... */
$('.overlay').click(function() {
  $('div').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
 display:none; 

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.popup, .popup2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;

    /* center it ? */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">Some popup text</div>
<div class="popup2">Hello world!!</div>

<!-- add a class to each element and a data attribute to identify the target element... -->
<p id="here" class="clickable" data-popup=".popup">Click 1</p>

<p id="there" class="clickable" data-popup=".popup2">Click 2</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I have modified it a bit so I can have ten options to be open.  If anyone would like to use it here is the link:  http://jsfiddle.net/hoqxmm0k  thank you once again for the help this is perfect and you have save me a headache! Cheers :)

Comment: Just out of interest how would you add a close button to this modal pop up?

Comment: There are lots of ways. You could do it like this ...http://jsfiddle.net/hoqxmm0k/2/ Notice that you can click the overlay or the close button to close the modal